# How to bind the body of a member-function of a class to procedure of an asm file in 64bit VS2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, masm, dynamic-linking, member-functions

Consider this code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
extern "C" void hello(); //THIS IS OK
class vector4
{
public:
    vector4(){hello();}
    extern "C" void  asm_proc(); //HERE IT THROWS AN ERROR 
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    hello();
    char buffer[256];
    vector4 vv;
    vv.asm_proc();
    int x=10+2;
    return 0;
}
```

Here I want to declare a class "vector4" and it's class member functions all written in assembly.
Note also that this is a 64bit project.

Here are the simple contents of asm file:

```
.code 
hello proc
    mov rax,234
    add rax,10
    ret 
hello endp
asm_proc proc
    mov rax,0
    ret 
asm_proc endp
end
```

I cant seem to find a way to call asm proc directly with the member function. 
I can bind the general function with asm by the means of extern "C" syntax. But same does not work inside a class.
So how do i properly bind the asm_proc to the class member-function?

Comment: chances are the name is mangled anyways up until asm_proc

Comment: How about just doing `inline void call_asm_proc() { asm_proc(); }`?

Comment: C doesn't support member functions, so you can't have a member function be `extern "C"`. You'll either have implement your assembly function using the largely undocumented Microsoft C++ ABI, or do something like David Wohlferd suggested. Note that depending on how you end up declaring `vector4` in C++ it's layout in memory may not be what you expect. It might have extra    members that you will have to somehow account for in your assembly code.

Comment: Thanks. I didnt think about inline. It will do the job..